# Count elements in each sub array in php

Tags: php, arrays, count

An example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) provides the following

```
<?php
$food = array('fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),
          'veggie' => array('carrot', 'collard', 'pea'));

// recursive count
echo count($food, COUNT_RECURSIVE); // output 8

// normal count
echo count($food); // output 2
?>
```

How can I get the number of fruits and the number veggies independently from the $food array (output 3)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```
echo count($food['fruits']);
echo count($food['veggie']);
```

If you want a more general solution, you can use a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($food as $type => $list) {
    echo $type." has ".count($list). " elements\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Could you be a little lazy, rather than a foreach with a running count twice and take away the parents.

```
// recursive count
$all_nodes = count($food, COUNT_RECURSIVE); // output 8

// normal count
$parent_nodes count($food); // output 2

echo $all_nodes - $parent_nodes; // output 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call `count()` on those keys.

```
count($food['fruit']); // 3
count($food['veggie']); // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function count the non-empty array values recursively.

```
function count_recursive($array) 
{
    if (!is_array($array)) {
       return 1;
    }

    $count = 0;
    foreach($array as $sub_array) {
        $count += count_recursive($sub_array);
    }

    return $count;
}
```

Example:

```
$array = Array(1,2,Array(3,4,Array(5,Array(Array(6))),Array(7)),Array(8,9));
var_dump(count_recursive($array)); // Outputs "int(9)"
```