# PHP Count Array Columns

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP array :

```
$food = array('fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),
              'veggie' => array('carrot', 'collard', NULL));
```

if I use this function :

```
$rows = count($food);
```

of course the result will be 2, but how to get number of array columns? so, I'm expecting 3 as a value of fruits and veggie columns. even though veggie has NULL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count elements in each sub array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496371/count-elements-in-each-sub-array-in-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ...I mean, if the columns are always the same, then why should we loop it as many as rows?

If the number of columns is always the same and you have at least one element in your `$food` array you can just probe the first/current element with [current()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)

```php
$columns = count(current($food));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try This: `array_map` with `count`.

```
<?php 
 $food = array('fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),
        'veggie' => array('carrot', 'collard', NULL));
 $typeTotals = array_map("count", $food);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($typeTotals);
```

OUTPUT:

> Array (
>       [fruits] => 3
>       [veggie] => 3 )

Comment: i would answer this way also, i'd also add `max` if the columns are jagged. `echo max(array_map('count', $food));`, anyway +1

Comment: @Ghost but i guess he is expecting both the keys in output.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin. It is just what i want to do! Thank you Suchit Kumar!

Answer (score 2):

```
$food = array('fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),
              'veggie' => array('carrot', 'collard', NULL));
$array = array_map('count', $food);
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach will create an array of counts, by type:

```
$rows = [];
foreach ($food as $type => $items) {
    $rows[$type] = count($items);
]
```

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for your answer. but, is there any other ways to count the columns without `foreach` loop? I mean, if the columns are always the same, then why should we loop it as many as rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
$food = array('fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),
                'veggie' => array('carrot', 'collard', NULL));

        echo count($food['fruits']);
```

However it would only work if you know the element e.g. 'fruits'.